# Encrypting an Arch installation w/ suspending state

Tags: linux, partitioning, encryption, arch-linux, swap

I'm trying to set up a fresh Arch install in a way similar to the Macbook I use for work. The Macbook is encrypted, and I want to recreate that encryption setup.

I need to:
- Fully encrypt the disk
- The disk is unlocked on login
- I want to be able to suspend the machine

I've been reading the Arch wiki, and I had some small questions about the steps I was going to take in using `dm-cryp`t & LUKS, no LVM:
1. The machine is UEFI. I'll have a [512 MiB GPT partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition#Create_the_partition), and this will be `/boot`, and be unencrypted.
2. I'll have a 741GB ext4 partition, which will be `/`, and will be encrypted. *How do I get it so that it is unencrypted at login?*
3. I'll have a swap space, lets say 8GB. *Do I need this, or would a swapfile be fine given there are only 2 partitions?*
4. How should I encrypt swap space? I used to use `lightdm-lock && pm-suspend` when i was moving this laptop around. My understanding is that this does not fall under [suspending to disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_encryption#With_suspend-to-disk_support) because `pm-suspend` saves state in RAM, *is that correct?*

If theres anything it seems I'm missing, or some mistakes I might be making, please point them out.

Thank you very much

Comment: Regarding the unlock at login, you will be prompted on boot up for the password/passphrase and at login stage it will be unlocked it sadly will be unlocked briefly before login name or at login.  Regarding po m-suspend that is correct the closest functional workaround is pm-suspend-hybrid (which suspends to ram up until a timeout is reached or power is too low then it 'hibernates' which is true suspend to disk but using hibernate natively is a known recipe for self-torture

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I felt was the case with respect to the login. I'm happy with `pm-suspend` doing what it does, I just need the minimal power consumption when i carry the machine between class and home; that said, I'm not sure if there is anything I should be doing to encrypt swap during that time.

Comment: Ideally swap would be luks'd either inside or as a separate partition and handled properly out the box

Comment: Right, I think my question was really once I have that swap space set up in the separate partition, will I need to take extra steps because of the necessity to "keep the swap space intact" when the disk is suspended, or is the disk not being suspended at all so I can ignore that?

Comment: As a separate partition you'd need to script it's closure with the others

Comment: So if I didn't write those scripts, the memory would be accessible while the machine was running, is that correct?

Comment: While running as in suspended yes.  It would separate from the main luks container but still possible rather trivially to connect the dots

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm going to consider this closed since your answers helped me figure out what I needed to do.